# What is a good way to write functional tests for website email functionality?

Tags: web-services, email, functional-testing, email-validation

Websites involve email functions, such as sending registration information, password reminders, etc.

I try to routinely run functional tests of complete websites from outside the website, and need a way to receive these test emails from an httplib based test script.

Previously, I have used anonymous email services, where the email content can be retrieved seconds or minutes after sending it, with an http GET.

These systems seem fragile, though, and they involve screen scraping, which is itself fragile.  Are there services that provide emails via an xml/json GETable interface?

Is there a fundamentally better way to approach this?  There are new email web-services like postmarkapp.com and yakmail.com; but the former does not receive mail, and the latter requires significant advance preparation.

My test tools are used for verification testing of live production systems, so mocking is not a good option.

Comment: Is this really an uninteresting question for web developers?  Does nobody test their website emailing in a systematic way?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to check whether your code sends the emails, and whether the content of the email is correct, mocking is the best solution. Take a look at [wiser](http://code.google.com/p/subethasmtp/wiki/Wiser). Unit tests and mock tests are faster and more helpful (for debugging) than integration/functional tests.

If you're doing a User acceptance test, in terms of looking at what the email looks like on a specific email client, then you have to test it manually and may be use scripts to screenshot your emails.

Comment: I had in mind regression testing, to ensure that working systems don't break over time, from some apparently unrelated change.  I remain somewhat puzzled as to why this isn't a higher profile issue with web devs.

Comment: A test's job is to tell you something went wrong.
If it also tells you what it is that went wrong, and why, it's more helpful.
Functional/Integration tests often fail to tell you what went wrong since there could be a chain of events that caused a test to fail.
OTOH, Unit tests can narrow down on a small fragment of code, because they don't test your app; they test a small fragment of code.
I do write F/I tests too, but I don't spend a lot of time on them. Also in the time a test opens a browser, runs a f/i test and closes it, I could have run several unit tests.